# Exporting bit data type data from SQL Server to PostgreSQL

Tags: sql-server, postgresql

I have table `tbl_mak` in SQL Server which contain's the following data:

**Table**:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_mak
(
   col_bit bit 
);

insert into tbl_mak values(1);
insert into tbl_mak values(0);
```

After exporting into Flat File (.txt) i got the following value's:

```
col_bit
True
False
```

And I have the following table in PostgreSQL 9.5:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_mak
(
   col_bit bit 
);
```

Now i want to import the exported data from SQL Server into PostgreSQL.

Script:

```
\COPY tbl_mak FROM 'D:\mak.txt'
```

Getting an error:

```
ERROR:  bit string length 5 does not match type bit(1)
```

Comment: Use 0/1 instead of true,false

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a table like below; Use `boolean` type for the field

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_mak
(
   col_bit boolean
);
```

and import data from text file like below

```
COPY tbl_mak FROM 'D:\mak.txt' WITH CSV HEADER DELIMITER AS ' '
```

Comment: Does this solution import `0/1` as same as in SQL server in PostgreSQL?

Comment: Because i don't want to store something like `t/f` in place of `0/1`.

Comment: You can import boolean values either  `True/False` or `0/1`, and Postgres stores boolean values as `t/f`

Comment: FYI,  If you want to get stored boolean values(`t/f`) as `0/1` use `select col_bit::int from tbl_mak`

Comment: Can you please help me for this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45273829/postgresql-export-data-from-sql-server-2008-r2-to-postgresql-9-5

Answer (score 0):

From [Postgres docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/datatype-bit.html)

> Writing bit without a length is equivalent to bit(1)

So mention the length

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_mak
(
   col_bit bit(5)
);
```

I think you can use [Boolean Type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/datatype-boolean.html) instead of `BIT`

Valid literal values for the "true" state are:

```
TRUE
't'
'true'
'y'
'yes'
'1'
```

For the "false" state, the following values can be used:

```
FALSE
'f'
'false'
'n'
'no'
'0'
```

Answer (score 0):

In Postgresql the bit datatype is different from SQL-Server in postgres it is

```
bit [ (n) ]   fixed-length bit string
```

but in SQL-server its a

```
integer data type that can take a value of 1, 0, or NULL
```

so in the file its TRUE/FALSE and when you are trying to import the data in postgresql its getting an error for more please go through the [link](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/datatype.html://)